# Llenar array por teclado dentro de un rango

Tags: java, array

No consigo exigir un rango de entrada a la hora de rellenar un array, os muestro:

```
 public static void llenar(int []sueldos, String [] nombres){

            for(int i = 0; i<nombres.length; i++){
                imprimir("Ingrese el nombre del empleado numero " + (i+1) + " : ");
                    nombres[i]=lectura.next();


                        imprimir("Ingrese el sueldo de " + (nombres[i]) + " : ");
                            sueldos[i]= lectura.nextInt();
                            if(sueldos[i]<100|| sueldos[i] >500){
                                    imprimir("El empleados no esta asegurado \n");

                            }
                                imprimir("\n"); 
            }                     
       }
```

Como veis cuando el sueldo introducido es menor que 100 o mayor que 500 muestro el mensaje de que el empleado no esta asegurado, pero lo almaceno en el array igualmente, lo que realmente me gustaria hacer es crear una estructura repetitiva dentro del bucle for que impidiera ingresar el sueldo a noser que estubiera dentro de ese rango, gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar un ciclo while

```
imprimir("Ingrese el sueldo de " + (nombres[i]) + " : ");
sueldos[i]= lectura.nextInt();
while(sueldos[i]<100 || sueldos[i] >500) {
    imprimir("El empleados no esta asegurado \n");
    sueldos[i] = lectura.nextInt()
}
```

Esto seguiría pidiendo el sueldo hasta que se ingrese correctamente y se guardaría en la misma posición. Espero te ayude

Comment: Cuidado, debería ser `lectura.nextInt()`

Comment: Tienes razón, ya lo edite gracias.

Comment: tu codigo me ayudo amigo lo que pasa es que tal como introduces el nombre te dice que el empleado no esta asegurado antes de comprobar la condicion quizas con un do while pueda arregarlo, gracias

Comment: Bueno mi idea era que primero hicieras la lectura normal como la tienes en tu código y después se verifica el while, esto es lo óptimo por que así te evitas hacer otra condición dentro y solo entra al while si no se ingreso el sueldo correcto, voy a editar revisa nuevamente.

Comment: muchas gracias jefe

Comment: Espero que te haya servido, saludos. P.D no entendí lo de "jefe" pero ayudo con mucho gusto.

Answer (score 1):

Aca te dejo un ejemplo que hice para vos

```
    String nombres[] = new String[3];
    int sueldos[] = new int[3];
    Scanner lectura = new Scanner(System.in);

    for(int i = 0; i<nombres.length; i++){
        System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del empleado numero " + (i+1) + " : ");
            nombres[i]=lectura.next();

                    do{
                        System.out.println("Ingrese el sueldo de " + (nombres[i]) + " : ");
                        sueldos[i]= lectura.nextInt();

                        if(sueldos[i] > 100 && sueldos[i] < 500){
                            System.out.println("El empleados no esta asegurado \n");
                        }

                    }while(sueldos[i] > 100 && sueldos[i] < 500);

                    System.out.println("\n");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Porque no haces una función de tipo boolean comparando  el sueldo ingesado con el rango,  de acuerdo al valor devuelto lo guardas o no

```
private boolean sueldoEnRango (double sueldo) {
    boolean estaEnRango=false;
    if (sueldo>100 && sueldo <500){
        estaEnRango=true;
    }
    return estaEnRango;
}
```

Luego harías en tu main

```
for( int i=O ; .....) {
    // ingresará por teclado el sueldo 
    ....
    if (sueldoEnRango==true){
        sueldo[i] = sueldo_ingresado;
    }
}
```

Comment: me gustaria no tener que utlizar returns, llevo realmente poco en el mundo de la programacion y aun no hemos llegado a ese punto, igualmente gracias por tu respuesta